# Migrating from log4j2 to logback

Tags: json, spring-boot, logging, log4j2, logback

I am currently migrating logging feature from `log4j2` to `logback`. I have some doubtful situations in the migration process. My doubts are related to JSON format conversions. First of all I will list down example code snippets from my logging module.

**Log4j2**

*pom file*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.logstash.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonevent-layout</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

*log4j2.xml file (Only JSON appender)*

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logFolder/jsonLog.json"
             filePattern="logFolder/%d{yyyyMMdd}_jsonLog-%i.json" >
    <JsonLayout properties="true" compact="true" eventEol="true">
        <KeyValuePair key="timestamp" value="$${date:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX}" />
    </JsonLayout>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB" />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
</RollingFile>
```

*Output JSON log*

```
{
   "instant":{
      "epochSecond":1635493457,
      "nanoOfSecond":835332800
   },
   "thread":"background-preinit",
   "level":"INFO",
   "loggerName":"org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version",
   "message":"HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.7.Final",
   "endOfBatch":false,
   "loggerFqcn":"org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.Log_$logger",
   "contextMap":{
      
   },
   "threadId":17,
   "threadPriority":5,
   "timestamp":"2021-10-29T13:14:17.835+05"
}
```

Due to the above default implementation I get this JSON formatted file.

**Logback**

*pom file*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

*logback.xml file (Only JSON appender)*

```
<appender name="JSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logFolder/${DATE}_jsonlog.json</file>
    <append>true</append>
    
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logFolder/${DATE}_jsonlog-%i.json</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
        <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
            <prettyPrint>false</prettyPrint>
        </jsonFormatter>
        <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampFormat>
        <appendLineSeparator>true</appendLineSeparator>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

*Output JSON log*

```
{
   "timestamp":"2022-02-01 08:48:57.863",
   "thread":"background-preinit",
   "level":"INFO",
   "loggerName":"org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version",
   "message":"HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.7.Final"
}
```

As seen above with default configuration of both `log4j2` and `logback`, outcome of the `JSON` is different. I want to get the same `JSON` format from `log4j2` while using `logback`.

According to my own research I did found out that I can write a class extending from `JacksonJsonFormatter` and override method `toJsonString`. There I can do the changes to the `JSON` keys and add values.

However, is there any convenient way of doing that without writing a separate class. With using `logback` I want to get the `threadId`, `threadPriority` etc. I want to do that only using `logback.xml`. In `log4j2` I didn't have to write a separate class to get the `JSON` file I currently get and I hope `logback` also supports doing that in another way. Can anyone please help me to figure out this and thank you in advance.

Comment: Why migrate if you have a working solution? If this is for the reason to think you are safer with logback that is the wrong reason. Also expecting one library to do the same as another library is also a bit weird (why would libraries exist if they did the same). You either need to add more configuration to get the logging yuou want or write your own `JsonLayout` for it (and override the `addCustomDataToJsonMap` method to include additional informatie if available).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for the response. In-fact I don't expect logback to work just as log4j2. I am attempting to get the same JSON format while using logback. What I tried is not to use any class for that and attempt to do it via only logback.xml but apparently I didn't find any way to achieve that. As you mentioned about witting own JSON layout, I did attempt via a custom class extending JacksonJsonFormatter already and it works. Thanks for the response again!

Comment: You can simply use the same `JacksonJsonFormatter ` and extend the `JsonLayout` class as I mentioned. The formatter should just do that formatting and you probably extended it to enrich your data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The migration from `log4j` to `logback` is done now. I was able to do that easily and it is not possible to get the default `JSON` format of `log4j` to `logback` because the defaults in `logback` is different. To change the to `JSON` format in `logback` either I have to modify the `logback.xml` file or add an extra class for that.